# VHDL Repeat one number to std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl, vivado, vivado-hls

I'm new to VHDL and I'm trying to figure out a better way to accomplish the following.
For example, I have one std_logic_vector of 2 bits called x and another std_logic_vector of 5 bits called y. I want to assign the first digit of x, which is x(0) to all 5 bits of y.
I thought of doing y(0) <= x(0), y(1) <= x(0)... but it's not very convenient.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: y can be assigned an aggregate whose elements all have the value of x(0). See e.g. IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.3 Aggregates, 9.3.3.3 Array aggregates "The index range of an array aggregate that has an **others** choice shall be determinable from the context. That is, an array aggregate with an **others** choice shall appear only in one of the following contexts: ... e) As a value expression in an assignment statement, where the target is a declared object (or member thereof), and either the subtype of the target is a fully constrained array subtype or the target is a slice name."

Comment: Instead of relying on rote learning how an assignment of an aggregate expression value assignment works is dependent on declarations of objects/values in the expression as well as the target object or slice. Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this assignment:

```vhdl
    y <= (others => x(0));
```

Comment: Without quantifying  what makes the incomplete example assignment statement 'not very convenient' what makes this answer more convenient? Seems the OP and you are dealing with subjective criteria.